# Question on continuous map between topologicla spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if $f(\overline{A})\subset \overline{f(A)}$ for all $A\subset X$ if and only if $\overline{f^{-1}(B)}\subset f^{-1}(\overline{B})$ for all $B\subset Y$.

I can only show equality instead of subset, which I guess is sufficient. But I'm not sure If I missed anything.

Suppose $f$ is continuous, and $A\subset X$, and note $\overline{f(A)}=\cap_{F \text{ closed in Y},f(A)\subset F}F\implies \cap_{f^{-1}(F) \text{ closed in X},A\subset f^{-1}(F)}f^{-1}(F)=\overline{A}$. Hence we have $\overline{f(A)}=f(\overline{A})$.

Any helpful hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In the first line: “[…] then $\overline A$ is closed which implies $f(\overline A$) is closed […]”. Why? That’s not a property of continuous maps.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks for the comment, I see my problem, I misread the definition , cts map only pull open sets to open set and closed sets to closed set, instead of maps them.

Comment: That’s right. As a hint, use the elementary fact that an inclusion of the form $f(*) \subseteq \star$ is equivalent to $* \subseteq f^{-1}(\star)$.

Comment: $f(\overline A)$ need not be closed in $Y$. E.g. $X=A=\overline A=(0,1)$ and $Y=(0,1]$  and $f=id_X.$

Comment: You can save a lot of typing with \to instead of \rightarrow .